# Difference between ActiveRecord's finder methods: take vs limit(1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Considering the following finder methods of ActiveRecord.

- `.take`. Example. `Account.take`
- `.limit(1)` Example. `Account.limit(1)`

Now,
both methods althought have different names but they generate the same query:

```
SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" LIMIT 1
```

So, what is the difference between `.take` & `.limit(1)`? or they are the same?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take)

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb, line 64
def take(limit = nil)
  limit ? limit(limit).to_a : find_take 
end
```

`take` returns an `Array` of records while `limit` returns an ActiveRecord Relation that can be chained with other relations.

Answer (score 5):

According to the code in [the API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take), the difference is that `limit` returns a `Relation` while `take` returns an `Array`.

To use `limit` you need a `Relation` and you get a relation. To use `take` you can also use an Array(since `Array` has `take` as well) and you also get an `Array`. So if you want an `Array` anyways, use `take` and you won't have to worry if the source object is `Relation` or `Array`.

Answer (score 2):

`limit(1)` will return an ActiveRecord::Relation, meaning you can chain more onto it (e.g. `Account.limit(1).where(...)`.

`take` will return an Array (either from an already-loaded query, or by executing `limit(1)` and returning the array)